# Trouble recompiling barcode scanner application: "Mutiply defined symbols found"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm struggling to recompile the "OPN2001 Companion Application" for my barcode scanner, on Visual Studio 2017 (v15.7.2).

The SDK can be downloaded here:
https://opticon.com/product/opn-2001/

In folder `OPN2001SDKv12\Applications\OPN2001 Standard Demo\Source`, there is a C++ solution that I'm trying to recompile with VS 2017 Community, but it keeps failing with the following errors:

```
LNK2005 "public: virtual __thiscall CMemDC::~CMemDC(void)" (??1CMemDC@@UAE@XZ) already
        defined in GridCtrl.obj    [uafxcwd.lib(afxglobals.obj) line 1]
LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found    [OPN200x.exe]
```

I had to install several additional components to Visual Studio, such as the CRT SDK, and accept a project migration to VS 2017, but maybe I'm still missing something?

Can you help me on this, or at least try and guess what is happening?
The company's support wasn't really helpful ...
Thank you.

(I can provide my full configuration, if you want.)

Comment: This does seem like the sort of thing the project's developers should look into rather than us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Opticon answered this:

> The version of MFC shipped with VS 2017 already has a `CMemDC` class.
>   Therefore, you have to rename `CMemDC` in the OPN project, or
>   put it in a namespace.

Just rename every occurrence of `CMemDC` in something else (e.g. `CMemDC_OPN`) in files "MemDC.h" (4 occurrences) and "GridCtrl.cpp" (1 occurrence).